# Where can I find the table of reputation required for privileges for different kind of sites?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

I remember seeing a table of reputation required for different privileges on graduated sites, public betas, private betas, and area51, respectively.

Now, I can't find this table. IIRC it was somewhere on the blog, but I can't find it. It doesn't seem to be linked from the FAQ either.